# Why do two different portals drop me into the exact same Nether coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I get a portal to spawn me in a different Nether location? Every portal I build immediately spawns me to the same Nether coordinates over lava.

For example, I have two Overworld portals: one at `891/71/113`, and one at `798/66/412`.

However, both spawn me in the Nether at `117/x/25`, which is directly over lava without a ledge.

I have tried creating portals at many different Overworld locations and I am always spawned at the same Nether location. These portals exists concurrently.

Screenshots (click to enlarge)

[image: Overworld Portal 1]
[image: Netherworld Portal 1]
[image: Overworld Portal 2]
[image: Netherworld Portal 1]

Comment: If you are playing locally, then you could always enable creative temporarily, which will make you invulnerable.  Take the gate make a safe area round your portal.

Comment: What are those, images for ANTS?!?!

Comment: @AnderBiguri "(click to enlarge)"

Comment: @johonn,  not all of them! Let me rephrase: what are half of those,  images for Ants?!

Comment: They were originally full size in the post. Someone else made them thumbnails but apparently didn't do some of them right.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Oops, that was me. Forgot to remove the 's' from the URL for the last two when I edited them. Fixed it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You aren't moving far enough away.

When you create a nether portal, the game searches in a radius of 128 blocks in the dimension you are traveling to, for an active portal. Since 1 block in the nether corresponds to 8 blocks in the overworld, you will actually need to travel at least 1024 blocks from your original portal in the overworld in order for the game to create a new portal.

Once you have done this successfully without falling into lava, you can make your way to the original portal and destroy it. Then you can create your portal in the nether wherever is most convenient for you, nearby the original one, and your first overworld portals should connect to it when you light it up.

It is surprising that you have nowhere to stand on your portal - I was under the impression that if a portal was created in the air, there would be an extra obsidian platform around it so that you didn't immediately fall off. In fact, if you just don't move when you first enter the portal, it shouldn't make you fall, you should be standing inside the portal. You can then hold shift to move slowly and avoid falling off the edge (holding shift prevents you falling off a block) and build away from the portal till you reach solid ground. If you do in fact fall immediately upon entering the nether, that's a glitch that I've never heard of.

Note: It is still possible to have multiple portals in a small space that all work properly and connect to the right portal. The key is that the game looks for the closest portal in the destination dimension, so if you build both portals in the "right" places (overworld x and z divided by 8 in the nether), before lighting either of them (Obviously you need an original set of portals to do this), then you can connect them properly.

Comment: I had the same understanding about spawning inside the ring of the portal. If I look up immediately after being spawned in the Nether, I can see the portal standing vertically, but one block away from where I had been standing.

Comment: Huh, strange. Guess the game was spawning you beside the portal for some weird reason...

Comment: Very nice answer!!!!

Comment: strange mechanic, but creates some fun experiences if you accidentally connect to another persons portal in multiplayer :)